# Como se insere números complexos em Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Eu já sei que ao inserir um `int` no print é necessário colocar o `%i`. Para o *float* é `%f` e para a *string* é `%s`. Agora como insiro booleanos e complexos? O `bool` e o `complex`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **Boolean**

Não há especificador de formato para `bool`. Você pode imprimi-lo usando alguns dos especificadores existentes para a impressão de tipos integrais ou fazer algo diferente:

Exemplo 1

```
 printf("%s", x?"true":"false");
```

Exemplo 2:

```
 #define btoa(x) ((x)?"true":"false")

 bool x = true;
 printf("%s\n", btoa(x));
```

Exemplo 3

```
 _Bool B = 1;
 printf ("%d\n",b);
```

## **Complex**

Um exemplo básico:

```
>>> n = 3.4 + 2.3j
>>> print '%05f %05fi' % (n.real, n.imag) // parte real e parte imaginária
3.400000 2.300000i
```

Além disso, é possível chamar o método `__format__` para construir tudo em tipos numéricos diretamente. Aqui está um exemplo:

```
>>> i = -3 # int
>>> l = -33L # long (só em Python 2.X)
>>> f = -10./3 # float
>>> c = - 1./9 - 2.j/9 # complex
>>> [ x.__format__('.3f') for x in (i, l, f, c)]
['-3.000', '-33.000', '-3.333', '-0.111-0.222j']
```

Note que isso funciona bem com partes imaginárias negativas também.

A partir de Python 2.6, você pode definir como os objetos de suas próprias classes para responder a sequências de formatos. Assim, você pode definir uma subclasse `complex` que pode ser formatada. Aqui está um exemplo:

```
>>> class Complex_formatted(complex):
...     def __format__(self, fmt):
...         cfmt = "({:" + fmt + "}{:+" + fmt + "}j)"
...         return cfmt.format(self.real, self.imag)
... 
>>> z1 = Complex_formatted(.123456789 + 123.456789j)
>>> z2 = Complex_formatted(.123456789 - 123.456789j)
>>> "Meus números complexos são {:0.5f} e {:0.5f}.".format(z1, z2)
'Meus números complexos são (0.12346+123.45679j) e (0.12346-123.45679j).'
>>> "Meus números complexos são {:0.6f} e {:0.6f}.".format(z1, z2)
'Meus números complexos são (0.123457+123.456789j) e (0.123457-123.456789j).'
```

Objetos dessa classe se comportam exatamente como números complexos, exceto que eles ocupam mais espaço e operam mais lentamente